# (django URLconf) page not found error only for urls with '-' character

Tags: regex, django, django-urls, urlconf

I have a weird problem can't figure out whats wrong, I get 404 errors for any url that contains a *'-'* character...

my urls.py in the project root works fine

```
url(r'^serialy/', include('movieSite.series.urls')),
```

next, is

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

              url(r'^$', views.serialy_index, name='serialy_index'), #this works 

              (r'^(?P<serial_title>[\w]+)/$', serial),

              )
```

The second one, using *serial_title*, works only if the series' title is something like, '*Dexter*,' or '*Continuum*.' But other series have titles like *'Family guy,'* so when I create the url I use a function that changes it to *'Family-guy,'* but for some reason it won't work for those titles with the '-' characters. I always get a 404 error like this

```
Using the URLconf defined in movieSite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^serialy/ ^$ [name='serialy_index']
^serialy/ ^(?P<serial_title>[\w]+)/$

^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, serialy/Whats-with-Andy/, didn't match any of these.
```

so here the url *serialy/whats-with-andy/* doesn't match, but if I visit *serialy/continuum* it works fine?? anyone have any ideas as to what could cause this?
Oh and this is what the view looks like

```
def strip(s):
    s.replace('-',' ')
    return s
def serial(request, serial_title=None) :
    s_title = strip(serial_title) 
    obj = Show.objects.get(title__icontains=s_title)
    #episodes = obj.episodes
    des = obj.description 
    img = obj.image 
    title = obj.title 

    t = get_template('serial.html')
    html = t.render(Context({
                             'the_title':title,'the_image':img,'the_description':des
                             })) 
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `[\w]+` only matches words and not special chars like `-`.

If you change it to `[-\w]+` it'll match "slug" urls.

Comment: thanks, now the url seems to work, but the view function gives me an error 'matching query does not exist.'

Comment: It's because you're returning `s` unmodified in your `strip` function. `replace()` doesn't modify the original string so you're trying to find a title that's still slugified.

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex is failing because '-' is not considered a match for \w.  See here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html